# React Filter the state without mutating the array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter

I know I am making a stupid mistake, but I can't seem to figure out what is it. I have a list in my state and depending on what the user selects from the dropdown, the state updates. But I am somehow mutating the state, so when the user selects something the second time, the list comes out to be empty and nothing displays on the screen.

This seems to be a popular question, and I have checked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42894774/react-filter-method-without-mutating-state), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44708416/react-filtering-the-state-without-ruining-it) and [here](https://codepen.io/pjmtokyo/pen/ZGVjVV?editors=0010).

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import Sidebar from './components/Sidebar'
import Map from './components/Map'

require('dotenv').config();

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    incidents: [],
    map: false,
    options: []
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    const res = await axios.get('https://data.sfgov.org/resource/wr8u-xric.json', {
      params: {
        "$limit": 500,
        "$$app_token": process.env.APP_TOKEN
      }
    })

    const incidents = res.data;
    this.setState({ incidents });

    console.log(incidents)

    this.getOptions()
  };

  getMap = () => {
    this.setState({ map: true });
    console.log(this.state.options)
  }

  handleChange = (e) => {
    const items =  this.state.incidents.filter(incident => incident['zip_code'] === e.target.value)
    this.setState({incidents: items})
  }

  getOptions = () => {
    this.state.incidents.map(incident => {
      if(!this.state.options.includes(incident['zip_code'])){
        this.state.options.push(incident['zip_code'])
      }
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1> San Francisco Fire Incidents</h1>
        <button onClick={this.getMap}> Get Map</button>

        <div id="main">
          <div style={{ width: '20%', height: '900px', display: 'inline-block', overflow: 'scroll', marginRight: '2px' }}>
            <span> Zip Code</span>
            <form>
              <select value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}>
              {this.state.options.map(option => (
                <option value={option} key={option}>{option}</option>
              ))}

              </select>
            </form>
          </div>
          {
            this.state.map ? <Map incidents={this.state.incidents} /> : ''
          }
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: what is your expected output and getting response from api?

Comment: Filter will always return a copy of the array.

Comment: @VahidAkhtar I get ann array of objects from the api which I save in the incidents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you don't maintain the initial state anywhere.

So after mutating the state and removing items, it's expected that the state variable will not contain all the original items.

Change to something like the following:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import Sidebar from './components/Sidebar'
import Map from './components/Map'

require('dotenv').config();

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    initialIncidents: [], 
    incidents: [],
    map: false,
    options: []
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    const res = await axios.get('https://data.sfgov.org/resource/wr8u-xric.json', {
      params: {
        "$limit": 500,
        "$$app_token": process.env.APP_TOKEN
      }
    })

    const incidents = res.data;
    this.setState({ initialIncidents: incidents });

    console.log(incidents)

    this.getOptions()
  };

  getMap = () => {
    this.setState({ map: true });
    console.log(this.state.options)
  }

  handleChange = (e) => {
    const items =  this.state.initialIncidents.filter(incident => incident['zip_code'] === e.target.value)
    this.setState({incidents: items})
  }

  getOptions = () => {
    this.state.incidents.map(incident => {
      if(!this.state.options.includes(incident['zip_code'])){
        this.state.options.push(incident['zip_code'])
      }
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1> San Francisco Fire Incidents</h1>
        <button onClick={this.getMap}> Get Map</button>

        <div id="main">
          <div style={{ width: '20%', height: '900px', display: 'inline-block', overflow: 'scroll', marginRight: '2px' }}>
            <span> Zip Code</span>
            <form>
              <select value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}>
              {this.state.options.map(option => (
                <option value={option} key={option}>{option}</option>
              ))}

              </select>
            </form>
          </div>
          {
            this.state.map ? <Map incidents={this.state.incidents} /> : ''
          }
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is something wrong in this part

```
getOptions = () => {
this.state.incidents.map(incident => {
  if(!this.state.options.includes(incident['zip_code'])){
    this.state.options.push(incident['zip_code'])
  }
})
```

}

You are always mutating the state options when you search. When no results found, the options array would be empty.

Try to do something like this.

```
  getOptions = () => {
    let options = [...this.state.options]
    this.state.incidents.map(incident => {
      if(!this.state.options.includes(incident['zip_code'])){
        options.push(incident['zip_code'])
      }
    })
    this.setState({options});
  }
```

Comment: I don't think the problem is getOptions, I think it has something to do with handleChange. I did try your suggestion, it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

`this.state.incidents` contains all the incidents and when the user makes the first selection you are changing the `incidents` array . 
The second selection is filtering the already filtered incidents from the first selection and returning empty . This might be causing this issue .

```
  const items =  this.state.originalIncidents.filter(incident => incident['zip_code'] === e.target.value)
    this.setState({incidents: items})
```