# Returning state to its original value after setState() without hardcoding

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm still new to React JS and was trying out my understanding of it by implementing a simple table. In my app I have a topBar component that includes a search bar, taking in the input and attempts to filter out the table.

I have managed that so far with the code below, however I find that after the first filter I have already trimmed down the table and can't do a new search that includes the already filtered out rows. Is there any way for me to have the full table back everytime I click the search button (I'm not allowed to use hooks)? And is there a better way to implement the .filter() than what I did? Thank you!!!!

```
import Table from './Table';
import Sidebar from './Sidebar';
import Topbar from './Topbar';
import Footer from './Footer';


//need img tag for this one
//import { ReactComponent as Logo1 } from './img/undraw_profile.svg';


class Home extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super();
        this.state = {


            tableData: [
                {

                    id: 1,
                    name: "Aiden",
                    position: "sdsdsd",
                    office: "sdasds",
                    age: 23,
                    startDate: "13/22/223",
                    salary: 12313,
                },
                {
                    id: 2,
                    name: "Ben",
                    position: "sdsdsd",
                    office: "sdasds",
                    age: 23,
                    startDate: "13/22/223",
                    salary: 12313,
                },
                {
                    id: 3,
                    name: "Kyle",
                    position: "sdsdsd",
                    office: "sdasds",
                    age: 23,
                    startDate: "13/22/223",
                    salary: 12313,
                },
                {
                    id: 4,
                    name: "Linda",
                    position: "sdsdsd",
                    office: "sdasds",
                    age: 23,
                    startDate: "13/22/223",
                    salary: 12313,

                },
            ],
            enterData: 'a',
        };
    }


    updateSearch = () => {

        const filteredData = this.state.tableData.filter(value => {
            return (
                //make this elegant
                value.name.toLowerCase().includes(this.state.enterData.toLowerCase()) ||
                value.position.toLowerCase().includes(this.state.enterData.toLowerCase()) ||
                value.office.toLowerCase().includes(this.state.enterData.toLowerCase()) ||
                value.age.toString().toLowerCase().includes(this.state.enterData.toLowerCase()) ||
                value.salary.toString().toLowerCase().includes(this.state.enterData.toLowerCase()) ||
                value.startDate.toLowerCase().includes(this.state.enterData.toLowerCase())
            );
        });

        this.setState({
            tableData: filteredData,
        })
    }

    getInput = (input) => {
        console.log(input)
        this.setState({ enterData: input, })
    }

    render() {
        return (

            <div id="wrapper">

                <Sidebar />
                <div id="content-wrapper" className="d-flex flex-column">
                    <div id="content">
                        <Topbar
                            searchData={this.state.searchData}
                            enterData={this.state.enterData}
                            updateSearch={this.updateSearch}
                            getInput={this.getInput}
                        />
                        <Table
                            tableData={this.state.tableData}
     
                        />

                    </div>
                    <Footer />

                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Home;
```

```
import Logo2 from './img/undraw_profile.svg';
class Topbar extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            input: ''
        }
    }


    updateSearch() {
        this.props.updateSearch();
    }

    //getvalue
    //pass that value to 
    getInput(evt) {
        this.props.getInput(evt.target.value);
    }

    //get value


    render() {


        return (

            <div>
                {/* Topbar */}
                <nav className="navbar navbar-expand navbar-light bg-white topbar mb-4 static-top shadow">
                    
                    {/* Topbar Search */}
                    <form className="d-none d-sm-inline-block form-inline mr-auto ml-md-3 my-2 my-md-0 mw-100 navbar-search">
                        <div className="input-group">
                            <input type="text" className="form-control bg-light border-0 small" placeholder="Search for..." aria-label="Search" aria-describedby="basic-addon2" onChange={evt => this.getInput(evt)} />
                            <div className="input-group-append">
                                <button className="btn btn-primary" type="button" onClick={() => this.updateSearch()}>
                                    <i className="fas fa-search fa-sm" />
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </nav>
                {/* End of Topbar */}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Topbar;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Filter the state without mutating the array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59710266/react-filter-the-state-without-mutating-the-array)

Comment: Just don't change your original set of data. Either make a second a state variable to set as your filter table data or make the original copy `this.data = ...` and filter from that